# Oracle on AWS RDS: is performance tuning no longer required?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, database-performance, oracle19c

My customer recently migrated from on-premises to the AWS Cloud. With SYSDBA locked down, I am aware that the Cloud has taken over many of the manual responsibilities -- if not all. When I review the DBA_ADVISOR_RECOMMENDATIONS there are a number of tuning recommendations. I'm questioning whether PGA/SGA parameters should still be maintained -- or not? TIA

Answer (score 0):

The answer I found is that yes, performance tuning is still appropriate, necessary, and complicated. The variations in resource parameters vary between instances in the same federation. The DBA advisor recommendations will be where I focus initial effort (alerts, segments, and bottlenecks). I've increased proactive monitoring and begun trimming tablespaces of allocated but unneeded storage.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).